# Gcc gives [1] 504 ...what is this?

Tags: gcc, matrix-decomposition

I compiled a c recipe and have no idea if I got ir right. It did compile. I matched a matrix to the specified format and ran:
./croutLU matrix1 & tee > b
The response the first time seemed successful but "b" was empty.
The second run of the same command generated:
[1] 654
And a hang...I rebooted, recompiled and ran it again:
[1] 504
I am using a freeBSD.
What is "[1] 504"
Can anyone tell me what happened here. Did something go right maybe? Or wrong?
Thank you
Jonathan Engwall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"[1] 654" is typically written when you launch a command in background, "1" indicate you have 1 process in parallel and "654" is the pid of the process

Example :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pwd &
[1] 5098
/home/pi
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Note : the command *jobs* gives the list of processes running in background

If I enter `pwd & tee > t` then I enter the line *aze* then ^d to finish the *tee* I have that (*Fini* means *done*) :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pwd & tee > t
[1] 5331
/home/pi
aze
[1]+  Fini                    pwd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat t
aze
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

As you can see *pwd* is started in background, in your case *./croutLU* is started in background and I suppose you just enter ^d to finish the tee so *b* is empty

Comment: This makes sense bruno. A similar question makes think I have do-nothing that will run forever...

Comment: @JonathanEngwall you can foreground a background process, just do `fg <n>` where _<n>_ is the number _[<n>]_ given by _jobs_

Comment: I will try that.